# Android Espresso navigating back to an activity

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am testing if form data is retained or not when back key is pressed and user navigates back to the form Activity.

**Expected Flow:** 
Press Register Button -> Goto Form page and fill it up -> Press back button -> Press Register Button -> Verify form data is retained

**Actual Flow:**
Espresso launches Form Page -> Press back button -> App Quits

Espresso start from Form Page because that's how the ActivityRule is defined.

```
public ActivityTestRule<RegisterActivity> mActivity = new ActivityTestRule<>(RegisterActivity.class);
```

I tried to startActivity() for the Registration Button page, but when I press back, it navigates back to the empty Form Page.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity.getActivity(), RegisterButton.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        oActivity.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```